# 128-bit compare-exchange in Java

Tags: java, atomic

I need to perform fast atomic CAS operation on a 128-bit integer in Java.

Modern CPUs support 128-bit CAS operations (i.e. CMPXCHG16B). Is there any way to use that in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no 128-bit integer in Java, so no.

You could technically achieve it through JNI, but any performance benefits may be lost.